# astyle: is there an option to add a space between `#include` and `<...>`?

Tags: astyle

For example, this code snippet:

```c
#include<math.h>
```

would becomes:

```c
#include <math.h>
```

I read the document and googled but didn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not. But it's ok since a regex can handle this situation well.